# do I need server if only access is for Internet

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have an office of about 30 people, half of whom only come in 2 days a week. we have a server 2016. Nothing is on the server, as we have Office365 [in the cloud].So there are no files, programs, etc that need to be accessed. The only thing that people need access to is the Internet as all our company programs are web-based. My IT people keep telling me that I must have a server and must route everyone through it, although I feel paying $30k a year just to access the Internet is ridiculous. My question, can we not by-pass the server by using a router to handle DHCP and DNS. When my 15 sales reps come in 2 days a week, they simply use WIFI and are not logged into the server [they seem to get the same things done as the others -who are hardwired into the network].This company is not local and remotes in to monitor our servers. To date over the past 8mo, they have had to deal with nothing.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you ***need*** a server to access the internet? No.

Comment: I've a big problem with this kind of question, as we (and possibly you) have no idea what might be the reason for your IT people to tell you that you need a server. So, it *might* be that what you really need could also be achieved by buying a 200$ class router or it might be there is some constraint that makes it necessary to pay $30k a year.  If you don't trust your staff, hire an outside consultant who can assess your situation.

Comment: $30k/year with 4 year life cycle and you have $120k servers. That budget is roughly 15-20 times the usual server/license costs for companies your size, even when they need one for hosting AD, print & file shares etc. Sounds you need to hire someone who knows how to migrate to AzureAD.

Answer (score 1):

Tell them they're forcing you into a hybrid-cloud environment which is more expensive and errorprone than being a "server-less", cloud-first company. Tell them other companies are trying to get to the place where you are now.

Your wifi infrastructure is already using DHCP and DNS, just get a switch and connect it that infrastructure for your hardwired comps. Ask them what they're really worried about, what problem do they think a server will solve?